# Power query, how I can get url adress

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

If I load simple Excel table in power query with only one column with tonns of url address,  how I can access to url address (not name of url) in power query?

Comment: If the URLs are in the form of hyperlink you will need a UDF (vba) to extract the link first. I believe there are answers in SO to do that. Also can find similar solution on Google. Btw you did not specify how you will `access` those URLs in power query. Please demonstrate your expected outcome.

Comment: If you want to get the information located at some URL (like you would if you typed the URL into the address bar of a browser), you can use `Web.Contents(url)` and pass the result to `Web.Page`. To do same thing for many URLs, you can use `List.Transform` (or `Table.Transform`). But your question is unclear (in terms of your input, objective and expected output).